# "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." Can't figure out

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, for-loop, matrix

I'm trying to run the following the loop (a bit sloppy/slow right now):

```
Sa1 = NaN(50,100);
Sd1 = NaN(50,100);
S1 = NaN(50,100);
e1 = NaN(50,100);
UdSd1 = NaN(50,100);
UdSa1 = NaN(50,100);
UaSd1 = NaN(50,100);
UaSa1 = NaN(50,100);
Ta1 = NaN(50,100);
Td1 = NaN(50,100);
p1 = NaN(50,100);
q1 = (1);
r = (2/3);
paths = 100;
p1 = [linspace(0.01,1); zeros(50, 100)];
%%
for t=1:5
     for i=1:paths
         if (p1(t,i) < .5)
             e1(t,i) = (1-r*(1-p1(t,i)))*(1-q1*r);
             syms A D
             [A, D] = solve([A == (p1(t,i)*r*(e1(t,i)+q1*r)+(1-e1(t,i))*(1-p1(t,i))*(1+q1*r)*D+(1+q1*r)*(1-r)*p1(t,i)*e1(t,i))/((p1(t,i)+(1-e1(t,i))*(1-p1(t,i)))*(1+q1*r)), D == ((1-p1(t,i))*r*(1-e1(t,i)+q1*r)+e1(t,i)*p1(t,i)*(1+q1*r)*A)/(((1-p1(t,i))+(e1(t,i)*p1(t,i)))*(1+q1*r))], A<=1, A>=0, D<=1, D>= 0, [A, D], 'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints', true);
             solA1 = A;
             solD1 = D;
             vpa(solA1);
             vpa(solD1);
             Sa1(t,i) = vpa(solA1);
             Sd1(t,i) = vpa(solD1);
             S1(t,i) = p1(t,i)*Sa1(t,i) + (1-p1(t,i))*Sd1(t,i);
             UdSd1(t,i) = -(((1-p1(t,i))*(r*(Sd1(t,i)-((1-e1(t,i)+q1*r)/(1+q1*r)))^2)+(1-r)*(Sd1(t,i)^2))+e1(t,i)*p1(t,i)*(Sd1(t,i)-Sa1(t,i))^2);
             UdSa1(t,i) = -(((1-p1(t,i))*(r*(Sa1(t,i)-((1-e1(t,i)+q1*r)/(1+q1*r)))^2)+(1-r)*(Sa1(t,i)^2)));
             UaSd1(t,i) = -((p1(t,i)*(r*(Sd1(t,i)-((e1(t,i)+q1*r)/(1+q1*r)))^2)+(1-r)*(Sd1(t,i)-e1(t,i))^2));
             UaSa1(t,i) = -((p1(t,i)*(r*(Sa1(t,i)-((e1(t,i)+q1*r)/(1+q1*r)))^2)+(1-r)*(Sa1(t,i)-e1(t,i))^2) + (1-e1(t,i))*(1-p1(t,i))*(Sa1(t,i)-Sd1(t,i))^2);
             Ta1(t,i) = (1-p1(t,i))*(UaSa1(t,i)-UaSd1(t,i));
             Ta1(t,i) = max(0,Ta1(t,i));
             Td1(t,i) = p1(t,i)*(UdSd1(t,i)-UdSa1(t,i));
             Td1(t,i) = max(0,Td1(t,i));
             p1(t+1,i) = (Ta1(t,i) - Td1(t,i))*p1(t,i)*(1-p1(t,i)) + p1(t,i);
        else
            e1(t,i) = (1);
            syms A D
            [A, D] = solve([A == (p1(t,i)*r*(e1(t,i)+q1*r)+(1-e1(t,i))*(1-p1(t,i))*(1+q1*r)*D+(1+q1*r)*(1-r)*p1(t,i)*e1(t,i))/((p1(t,i)+(1-e1(t,i))*(1-p1(t,i)))*(1+q1*r)), D == (e1(t,i)*p1(t,i)*A)/((1-p1(t,i))+e1(t,i)*p1(t,i))], A<=1, A>=0, D<=1, D>= 0, [A, D], 'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints', true);
            solA1 = A;
            solD1 = D;
            vpa(solA1);
            vpa(solD1);
            Sa1(t,i) = vpa(solA1);
            Sd1(t,i) = vpa(solD1);
            S1(t,i) = p1(t,i)*Sa1(t,i) + (1-p1(t,i))*Sd1(t,i);
            UdSd1(t,i) = -(((1-p1(t,i))*(r*(Sd1(t,i)^2)))+e1(t,i)*p1(t,i)*(Sd1(t,i)-Sa1(t,i))^2);
            UdSa1(t,i) = -(((1-p1(t,i))*(r*(Sa1(t,i)^2))));
            UaSd1(t,i) = -((p1(t,i)*(r*(Sd1(t,i)-((e1(t,i)+q1*r)/(1+q1*r)))^2)+(1-r)*(Sd1(t,i)-e1(t,i))^2));
            UaSa1(t,i) = -((p1(t,i)*(r*(Sa1(t,i)-((e1(t,i)+q1*r)/(1+q1*r)))^2)+(1-r)*(Sa1(t,i)-e1(t,i))^2) + (1-e1(t,i))*(1-p1(t,i))*(Sa1(t,i)-Sd1(t,i))^2);
            Ta1(t,i) = (1-p1(t,i))*(UaSa1(t,i)-UaSd1(t,i));
            Ta1(t,i) = max(0,Ta1(t,i));
            Td1(t,i) = p1(t,i)*(UdSd1(t,i)-UdSa1(t,i));
            Td1(t,i) = max(0,Td1(t,i));
            p1(t+1,i) = (Ta1(t,i) - Td1(t,i))*p1(t,i)*(1-p1(t,i)) + p1(t,i);
         end
     end
 end
```

Forgive me, I'm new at this and trying to learn. 
My issue is with the `if/else`. The **p matrix** evolves with each row according to the **t process**. When `p < .5`, it's supposed to follow the first part `"if,"` and otherwise the second `"when."` However, once I hit `t=3`, the code stops and says
 `"Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."` at the `i=51` mark. I know it's an issue with the fact that the code is evolving such that a column that previously was `<.5` is now `>.5`, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix it.

Anyone have any ideas? Appreciate the help!

Comment: In which line are you getting this error ?

Comment: Use `dbstop if error` to set a breakpoint when an error is thrown, then check the left side of the = and the right side. The error says that these sizes don't match.

Comment: The code stops running when the error is thrown. Using `dbstop if error` doesn't seem to give me any additional information. However, I already know that the code stops running at i=51, t=3. I'm guessing it has something to do with `p1(t+1,i) = (Ta1(t,i) - Td1(t,i))*p1(t,i)*(1-p1(t,i)) + p1(t,i);` and the if/else statement, but I've tried modifying in a number of ways to no avail. The columns 49 - 52 of the p1 matrix look like this after the code stops running:

     [.49     .5     .51     .52;
     .497     .521     .528     .536;
     .503     .537     -     - ]